# Android: Launching Portrait-only Activity from Landscape causes dialogs to go offscreen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application that supports portrait and landscape orientations. Within this application, there is an activity that is portrait only. In the new activity, MaterialDialogs (https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) are built in the OnCreate method. When the initial activity is in landscape mode and the new activity is started, it will switch to portrait, but the MaterialDialogs will sometimes be sized as if they are in landscape (and therefore extend offscreen). This seems to happen if the activity starts before the orientation change animation begins, but whether or not that happens seems arbitrary.

My initial solution was to simply show and immediately dismiss the dialogs after they are built, so the next time they are shown, they will resize themselves. This worked on a Moto X running Android 7.1.2. However, it did not work for a Nexus 6 running Android 7.0 as the dialogs do not resize themselves.

Other things I have tried with no luck are:

- Building the Material Dialogs in OnStart as well as OnResume
- Building the MaterialDialogs after a 300ms delay (I don't know if this would work with a longer delay but even if it would, I can't have a longer delay before the dialogs are shown)
- Changing the AndroidManifest both with and without the "orientation" flag under `android:configChanges`

Snippet from AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
android:configChanges="screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|orientation|screenSize"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/Theme.myTheme"
android:resizeableActivity="false" />
```

So, has anyone seen this and come up with a fix? If not, is there a way to delay the call to OnCreate until the orientation animation is finished? Lastly, is there a fix/workaround for the Nexus 6 not resizing the dialogs automatically?

Comment: when you declared portrait orientation in manifest, how u support landscape ?

Comment: @AalapPatel I only specified "portrait" orientation for MyActivity. MyActivity is launched from a different activity that does not have an orientation specified in the manifest